# PHP Compare two multidimensional arrays by key and value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am busy learning PHP and was looking for a way to compare two associative arrays by both key and value and then find the difference of the two i.e.

If I had an associative array with:

```
array (size=2)
  'x15z' => int '12' (length=2)
  'x16z' => int '3' (length=1)
```

And another with the following:

```
array (size=1)
  'x15z' => int 1
```

I am trying to find the difference between the two associative arrays and I am currently trying to use array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2) and this works in the case whereby one element is missing from the other however in the instance described above, the difference is

```
array (size=2)
  'x15z' => int '12' (length=2)
  'x16z' => int '3' (length=1)
```

as opposed to what I am looking for which is:

```
array (size=2)
  'x15z' => int '11' (length=2)
  'x16z' => int '3' (length=1)
```

Whereby the value difference is also calculated.

Is there any logical way to calculate the difference of two associative arrays based upon their keys and values? Thanks!

Comment: You actual output (`the difference is {code}`) looks identical to your expected output (`for which is {code}`)??

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: Ok, i see what you are getting at, but you need to define the rules. What would be the expected output if the second array was: `array (size=1) 'x15z' => int 11` How about if it was `array (size=1) 'x15z' => int 13`? `1 and 1` or perhaps `1 and -1`? How about if the second array contains a string or an object instead of an integar

Comment: @Tim he wants to calculate the difference between the integer values of the array elements that dont match. However he hasnt yet defined how that difference should be calculated

Comment: I am looking to find the difference between the two arrays in terms of their elements and their key values. i.e. so if the either x15z or x16z then that would not be in the resulting difference array but in this case they are both present and I am looking to compare the two values and get the difference of them i.e. x15z in array 1 is 1 and x15z in array 12 is  so the difference is 11. If that makes sense? Let me know otherwise I will update the question again!

Comment: I edited my comment - i understand the concept, not the specific rules. sure `12-1=11` but what about `4-'a large cat'=?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function calculateDifference($array1, $array2){
  $difference = array();
  foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if(isset($array2[$key])){
      $difference[$key] = abs($array1[$key] - $array2[$key]);
    }else{
      $difference[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  foreach($array2 as $key => $value){
    if(isset($array1[$key])){
      $difference[$key] = abs($array1[$key] - $array2[$key]);
    }else{
      $difference[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $difference;
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way of accomplishing this using PHP array methods? Just out of interest?

Comment: I don't know, but if there is it will be documented somewhere here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php